# How to standardise padding and other attributes in dynamically-created TextViews?

Tags: android, textview, styles

My app creates a number of `ScrollViews` which contain `TextView` items. The `TextView` items are created at runtime and are populated from the results of `SQL queries`. I'd like to standardise the padding (and other attributes such as colour) of these `TextViews`, without coding separate `setPadding` statements for each. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Why not create a custom view that extends TextView and have it initialize your desired settings? Or create an xml layout file containing just the TextView with your desired settings and use the LayoutInflater to inflate it at runtime?

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll look into the XML/LayoutInflater option. It sounds like an ideal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Guardanis said, create an XML file containing just the TextView with the desired settings and then use the [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to create it. This would probably be your best option since it separates out the presentation layer.